# Cannot install Ionic on macOS 10.12.3

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

I have had considerable trouble trying to install Ionic on my Mac. I have tried every suggestion posted on the web without success. I have tried installing as root, using sudo, you name it.

Using Homebrew I have successfully installed node : v6.10.0 and npm v4.1.2.

```
Issuing: "npm install -g cordova ionic"
Results in:
npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! path /Users/craigmaxey/.npm
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir '/Users/craigmaxey/.npm'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir '/Users/craigmaxey/.npm'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/craigmaxey/.npm' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.3262676290
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'npm-debug.log.3262676290'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'npm-debug.log.3262676290'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'npm-debug.log.3262676290' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/craigmaxey/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Worst comes to worst, clear out the /usr/local/bin/npm folder and try to install

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir '/Users/craigmaxey/.npm'
```

indicates that you're missing write privileges on `/Users/craigmaxey/.npm`. Usually, you can fix this by running npm with `sudo`:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova ionic
```

If this doesn't work for you (since you mentioned you already tried `sudo`), please add the *exact* error message you get from running this *exact* command.

Comment: If this is true, not sure how mac works but on Linux you're better of installing nodeJS through NVM - do the mac research, do not sudo the npm

Comment: Thank you Frank and Jay for your timely and helpful feedback!  The exact command is obscure in my original post but was: "npm install -g cordova ionic". I had also tried using the "sudo npm install -g cordova ionic" command several times during my journey, without success. I have also read a lot of posts regarding the suggestions of using "sudo" and not. At this point, I need to declare surrender.  I don't feel I can put the effort into really understanding all of the issues well enough to be confident in a solution (chmod directories etc.)  Repeating... THANK YOU for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I too was getting the same errors and was able to get it to install following these steps:

1. Using Finder, manually create a folder called "@ionic" at this location: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic`
2. Using finder, if "ionic" folder exists at `/usr/local/bin/ionic`, delete it
3. run `sudo npm install -g @ionic/cli`